# What are the significant differences between TypeScript and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

What are the differences between Typescript and Javascript? What are the language design goals of each and how do these design goals differ?

How compatible are libraries and frameworks intended to be used with Javascript, for example jquery, also compatible with Typescript?

Some examples would be helpful.

Comment: typescript gives you strong typing and compile time checking. javascript doesn't.  jquery is a library and can be used with both. typescript is a superset of javascript.

Answer (score 15):

I've used typescript for a few small hobby projects and I'm convinced that it is the perfect Javascript replacement. My favorite features were:

- Declaration files. With declaration files you can add type informations to your javascript libraries. This structural information will get you fantastic intellisense support in VisualStudio.
- "Standard" OOP. If you come from a C# or Java background you probably won't even need a typescript tutorial. It just works. You have classes, interfaces, access modifiers, extension mechanisms, ...
- Built-in support for modules. Typescript has a slightly confusing module system. You can split your code into several .ts files and just append them but you can also create different modules.

And finally: The syntax. Sometimes it's the small things that have the biggest impact. To me the syntax of typescript feels just perfect. Let me give you a few examples:

Type annotations with ":" and type inference

```
var a = 5; //infers that a has the type number
var canvas : HTMLCanvasElement = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
// automatically casts to the canvas type. Intellisense will now suggest all the canvas specific methods
```

Arrays that work as lists, stacks, ...

```
var array= []; //dynamic type
array.push(1);
array[1]=2;
array.pop();

var array2 : number[] = []; //typed array
array[0]=2;
array[1]="hello"  //compile time error. You've got to love the type system. Finally you can trust your collections
```

And functions with the arrow syntax as lambdas:

```
var array=[];
array.push(1);
//...
array.forEach((num)->{alert(num);});
//for single statement functions you can write
array.forEach((num)->alert(num));
```

Now typed arrays and lambdas combined:

```
var array: number[]=[];
array.push(1);
//...

//let's assume you want to work with the data in the array. You've got to filter it and process it. Lambdas will come in handy, as well as the type inference
array.filter((num)->num>3).map((num)->num*2).forEach((num)->alert(num));

// the first lambda with the comparison is fully type safe. The compiler knows the type of the array. Therefore it can infer the type of the parameter num and will check if num can be compared to a number
```

I really enjoyed using typescript. It will significantly increase your productivity. And there's even more to come: <del>http://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Roadmap</del>
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap

The 0.9 release will feature generics and for the 1.x versions they plan to implement async/await calls.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for your time in answering the question. Typescript is client Side C# which is converted to JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a collection of videos on TypeScript:

http://channel9.msdn.com/search?term=typescript

Basically it adds optional static typing to Javascript, so all the advantages of static typing brought to Javascript.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth for the link. I just viewed the first video. It was informative. will do the remaining sometime later. :)

Answer (score 3):

JQuery and Typescript are not mutually exclusive, as it is fairly common to use JQuery in Typescript.  The main benefit of using Typescript over Javascript is the addition of type checking.  This allows you to create interfaces and develop by contract.  In larger projects, it can be beneficial to have type checking, but that is a subjective preference.

Comment: Thanks Sean. Till now I use javascript for client side validation and to enable or disable the controls in the page based on client selection. most of my business logic is written in C#. Creating interfaces in the client side is new to me. how will the interfaces in the client side be useful?

Comment: It depends on your use case.  We have developed a couple of fairly large client-side applications in Typescript, so it has been nice to have type checking, while being able to write decoupled code via interfaces.  Again, it's subjective.

Comment: As per my understanding creating interfaces, classes everything depends on your database(or table) structure. In your case, do you mean the typescript code will contain some business logic too? if so is it possible for the end user to see the logic? Also I read that the .ts file will be compile to .js file.

Comment: Interfaces and classes don't have anything to do with databases or tables.  There is no business logic (other than validations for purely UX reasons.  Actual validations occur server side) on the client, but there are plenty of controls and UI elements, API clients, etc. that are represented via interfaces and clients.  You are correct about Typescript compiling to Javascript.

Comment: Thanks Sean,I did some reading about Typescript and what I can understand is Typescript does not provide any extra functionality than JavaScript except for static typing and easy maintainability of the code. If I have a 1000 line JavaScript, it may be worth to consider Typescript. But if i just have few alert statements, it does not matter if I use JavaScript or Typescript. Right?

Comment: Well, it provides the ECMAScript 6 lambda syntax, as well as a more familiar (for me anyway) class based inheritance, as opposed to the prototype based inheritance.  Again, that's a subjective preference.